# Mathematical symbol for disjoint set union

Tags: symbols, amsmath

In our lecture script, we use the notion of disjoint set union. It uses a special symbol to differentiate the disjoint from the usual set union, where we add an extra dot inside of the `\cup` symbol. Is there something like a `\bigudot`? Or any other way to add a centered dot to any symbol?

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: In my opinion, the best notation is \uplus.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**Edit** I thought amssymb provides `\cupdot` which does what you want... but it doesn't.

[`\usepackage{MnSymbol}`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mnsymbol/) provides `\cupdot` and `\bigcupdot` but is incompatible with `amssymb` which is unfortunate.

Sometimes [disjoint union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union) is depicted using `\sqcup` which has the advantage of being in `amssymb`

Comment: The MnSymbol package seems to do the job perfectly. I'm not using the amssymb package anyway, so their incompatibility is not a problem for me. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 55):

Another possibility to go around the problem that there is no such symbol in `amssymb` is to use the dot-accent: `\dot{\bigcup}` or also `\dot\bigcup`. This works for all symbols, and might very well be the reason that there are no dotted symbols in `amssymb`.

To let TeX treat such a new construct as an operator in terms of spacing though, you need to use `\mathop` and `\mathbin`, that's to say `\mathop{\dot{\bigcup}}` and `\mathbin{\dot{\cup}}`.

Comment: The usual cupdot has the dot in the body of the union symbol. The dot accent has it on top. 

Answer (score 37):

Disjoint union is also sometimes written using `\coprod`, since it is in fact the coproduct in the category of sets.

Comment: Completely agree with this one.  I've never used "cup with a dot in it" and always use either `\coprod` or `\amalg` (slightly smaller for inline maths).

Comment: This should really be a comment to the `\coprod` answer above, but I don't have any reputation. Though it is true that this symbol describes disjoint union, the usage is slightly different, I think. As described, this is the coproduct in the category of sets or what one might describe as the "exterior disjoint union" whereas the symbol with the dot is usually used for subsets of a given set to denote the union of two sets and state in passing that they are disjoint. In particular, `\{1,2\} \dot\union \{3,4\} = \{1,2,3,4\}` is a true statement whereas `\{1,2\} \coprod \{3,4\}` and `\{1,2,3,4\}`

Answer (score 30):

Another way is the following:

```
\makeatletter
\def\moverlay{\mathpalette\mov@rlay}
\def\mov@rlay#1#2{\leavevmode\vtop{%
   \baselineskip\z@skip \lineskiplimit-\maxdimen
   \ialign{\hfil$\m@th#1##$\hfil\cr#2\crcr}}}
\newcommand{\charfusion}[3][\mathord]{
    #1{\ifx#1\mathop\vphantom{#2}\fi
        \mathpalette\mov@rlay{#2\cr#3}
      }
    \ifx#1\mathop\expandafter\displaylimits\fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\cupdot}{\charfusion[\mathbin]{\cup}{\cdot}}
\newcommand{\bigcupdot}{\charfusion[\mathop]{\bigcup}{\cdot}}
```

The `\charfusion` macro is built on `\moverlay` (by D. Arseneau).

Examples:

```
$A\cupdot B$

\[ \bigcupdot_{i\in I} A_{i} \]
```

[image]

Comment: wouldn't `\ooalign{\bigcup\cr\cdot}` work here too? (With proper `\mathpallete` and `\mathop` usage of course.)

Comment: i also have this question

Answer (score 14):

A redacted version from [symbols](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf):

```
\newcommand{\cupdot}{\mathbin{\mathaccent\cdot\cup}}
```

This shows @egreg's solution, "my" solution, and @Vilietha's solution side by side:
[image]

Not much difference between egreg's and mine, but maybe less to type ;-)

Comment: Why doesn't this work with \bigcup or \bigcup@?

Comment: @JeffBurdges Well, it does work as long as you don't load `amsmath`, it just is not pretty. With `amsmath`, `\bigcup` is not just a math character anymore, so `\mathaccent` complains.

Comment: I fixed it with \nolimits even with amsmath loaded, still not pretty but no weird packages, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

If you use `xelatex` and `unicode-math` you can simply use the symbol ⊍ directly, or its alias `\cupdot`: $A ⊍ B \cupdot C$ renders with  XITS Math as [image: example].

Comment: You can use `unicode-math` with `lualatex` too.

Comment: The last time I tried it (about two months ago) some things like underbraces didn’t render correctly with lualatex. Is this fixed now?

Answer (score -1):

Here it is another way though dot not inside but above the cup:

```
$A \overset{\cdot}{\cup} B$
```

[image]

I would put plus instead of dot! would look nicer!

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do the dot inside union is

```
\cdot \hspace{-12pt}\bigcup
```

Comment: Why is this *easiest*? How does this scale when used in sub-/superscripts?