# Is a cupdot symbol available in amsmath?

Tags: symbols, amsmath

I'm looking for a command in `amsmath` that makes something like `\cupdot`  in `MnSymbol` (I hope spell it right...).

Look at the picture below:

[image: capdot]

i.e. a command that puts a dot instead of the "+".

One more thing: I don't want that the dot will be above the cup sign - the dot should be **inside** the cup.

Comment: I look here [List of Ams Symbols](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) but I didn't found nothing....:-( @mafp it's a great link what you gave me, but I didn't found it there).
Thank you!

Comment: Well, that was the goal ;-) Such symbol is not part of `amssymb`. But you can build one yourself: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52673/21591

Comment: Therefore, another possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3964/21591

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the preferred math font does not contain the symbol, it can be provided by putting `\cup` and `\cdot` together:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\cupdot}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@cupdot{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@cupdot}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\cup$\cr
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1\cdot$\hidewidth
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ a\cupdot b\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remarks:

- `\mathbin` keeps the spacing of a binary operator (like `\cup`) for the new symbol.
- The trick with `\mathpalette` ensures that the symbol adopts its size if used in fractions, subscripts, ...

### Variant with vertically centered dot and `\bigcupdot`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\cupdot}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@cupdot{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@cupdot}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\cup$\cr
    \sbox0{$#1\cup$}%
    \dimen@=\ht0 %
    \sbox0{$\m@th#1\cdot$}%
    \advance\dimen@ by -\ht0 %
    \dimen@=.5\dimen@
    \hidewidth\raise\dimen@\box0\hidewidth
  }%
}

\providecommand*{\bigcupdot}{%
  \mathop{%
    \vphantom{\bigcup}%
    \mathpalette\@bigcupdot{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@bigcupdot}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\bigcup$\cr
    \sbox0{$#1\bigcup$}%
    \dimen@=\ht0 %
    \advance\dimen@ by -\dp0 %
    \sbox0{\scalebox{2}{$\m@th#1\cdot$}}%
    \advance\dimen@ by -\ht0 %
    \dimen@=.5\dimen@
    \hidewidth\raise\dimen@\box0\hidewidth
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \bigcupdot a\cupdot b\]
\end{document}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\cupdot}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@cupdot{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@cupdot}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\cup$\cr
    \sbox0{$#1\cup$}%
    \dimen@=\ht0 %
    \sbox0{$#1\cdot$}%
    \advance\dimen@ by -\ht0 %
    \dimen@=.5\dimen@
    \hidewidth\raise\dimen@\hbox{$\m@th#1\cdot$}\hidewidth
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \bigcupdot_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i\cupdot b \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you!!
Both paragraphs are needed?

Comment: and what is the command to do it bigger? for a display eq.

Comment: @YoavFridman The part between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` inclusively is needed.

Comment: @YoavFridman The examples show the symbol in displayed equations, do you mean a symbol like `\int`/`\sum`/`\bigcup`?

Comment: There is an error at your code... I put at Lyx Preamble and it's says that `\begin{document}` is missing....

Comment: yes! :-) Thats what I mean.... @Heiko

Comment: This is the best definition I found! Thanks! One request: is it possible to make \cdot a parameter, so I can stick any symbol into union?

Comment: It would be cool if I can parametrize it by symbol inserted in the middle (currently \cdot). Is it possible?