# Including bigcupdot in Lyx

Tags: math-mode, symbols, lyx

I need to use `\bigcupdot` which according to this link is available in `mnsymbol`.

I downloaded the package through MikTeX Package Manager. When I open a document  in Lyx, I went to Lyx Preamble and added `\usepackage{mnsymbol}`. When I try to write a formula it doesn't accept `\bigcupdot` and other stuff. How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know Lyx, but note that the package should be loaded as `MnSymbol` and not `mnsymbol`: `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`.

Comment: Also, why `$\usepackage{...}$` and not `\usepackage{...}`?

Comment: That still does not work. About the '$' they are just to emphasize its a code (after ````) they are not needed anymore.

Comment: How doesn't it work, what happens? For suggestions other than `MnSymbol` see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110976/is-a-cupdot-symbol-available-in-amsmath/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3964/mathematical-symbol-for-disjoint-set-union/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean "doesn't accept" ? LyX doesn't support `\bigcupdot` so if you type it into an equation it won't show as a graphical symbol, but it will still typeset properly when you preview it as PDF, assuming that you've typed it in correctly and put the correct `\usepackage{..}` line in your preamble.

If you want it to look good in LyX too you have two options:

1. Turn on instant preview. This is in preferences under display. With this turned on, every individual equation will be run through LaTeX whenever the cursor is not currently in it for editing.
2. Instead of using `\bigcupdot` in your equations, create a math macro (you could call it `\mybigcupdot` or something) and make that map straight to `\bigcupdot` (put this in the "TeX" field). You can then make it display something that looks approximately correct e.g. `\dot\cup` (put this in the "LyX" field) so that you something a bit more visual for editing.