# Is there any operator like ⊎, only with a minus sign instead of a plus sign?

Tags: symbols

I need to use an operator similar to ⊎ in my paper. The required symbol looks like ⊎, only with minus sign instead of a plus sign, inside the "U". I haven't been able to find any symbol for this. Can someone please give me some pointers as to where I can find that symbol?

Comment: You can most likely use modified code from [Mathematical symbol for disjoint set union](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52673/5764) or [Is a `\cupdot` symbol available in `amsmath`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110981/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\stackMath
\[\def\stacktype{L}\setstackgap{L}{.4ex}
x\mathrel{\stackon{\cup}{\scriptscriptstyle+}}y
 \mathrel{\stackon{\cup}{\scriptscriptstyle-}}z
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\moverlay{\mathpalette\mov@rlay}
\def\mov@rlay#1#2{\leavevmode\vtop{%
   \baselineskip\z@skip \lineskiplimit-\maxdimen
   \ialign{\hfil$\m@th#1##$\hfil\cr#2\crcr}}}
\newcommand{\charfusion}[3][\mathord]{
    #1{\ifx#1\mathop\vphantom{#2}\fi
        \mathpalette\mov@rlay{#2\cr#3}
      }
    \ifx#1\mathop\expandafter\displaylimits\fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\cupmin}{\charfusion[\mathbin]{\cup}{-}}



$ C \cupmin D $
```

Source Macro

[Mathematical symbol for disjoint set union](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3964/mathematical-symbol-for-disjoint-set-union/52673#52673)