# \cupdot gives "Undefined control sequence" with MikTek on Windows 7

Tags: math-mode, miktex, math-operators

I am using MikTek 2.9 on Windows 7.  When I try to use \cupdot, in math mode, I get an "Undefined control sequence" error message.  Is there a package that I need to include to use \cupdot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load `MnSymbol`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol} 

\begin{document}
$\cupdot$
\end{document}
```

Comment: That might not be such a good idea, as the font is not designed to be used with CM.

Comment: That fixed the problem.  The only caveat is that I had to remove mathpazo in order to avoid the message "\mathdollar already defined".  That was not really a problem in my case.

Comment: @daleif I am aware of that but the OP did not provide any more information on the font. This is the easiest way to go and I would always try it first.

Comment: Is CM a type of font?

Comment: I am using the Palatino font.

Comment: @OtagoHarbour The command doesn't work with `amsmath`. There are a couple of threads which provide help in this case, for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110976/is-a-cupdot-symbol-available-in-amsmath

Answer (score 4):

the symbol you want is defined in the `MnSymbol` package.

however, loading that entire package can cause problems.
instead, arrange to access just the symbol(s) you need selectively.

see the question [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/579)

the particular font that contains `\cupdot` can be found in the
`MnSymbol` documentation -- `texdoc mnsymbol` or view it from ctan.