# How to make dot in the defined bigcupdot automatically change size?

Tags: math-operators

I searched in the TSE and found a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110981/140814) to define the `\bigcupdot`. As you see the size of the dot in the `\bigcupdot` is fixed no matter whether it's in display style or not. I tried to use `\ifx` command to make the dot automatically change its size but failed! **Who can fix the following codes**? Any help is welcome.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\bigcupdot}{%
  \mathop{%
    \vphantom{\bigcup}%
    \mathpalette\@bigcupdot{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@bigcupdot}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\bigcup$\cr
    \sbox0{$#1\bigcup$}%
    \dimen@=\ht0 %
    \advance\dimen@ by -\dp0 %
    \sbox0{%
    \ifx\displaystyle\scalebox{1.7}{$\m@th#1\cdot$}\else
    \ifx\textstyle\scalebox{1.4}{$\m@th#1\cdot$}\else
    \ifx\scriptstyle\scalebox{1.2}{$\m@th#1\cdot$}\else
    \scalebox{1.1}{$\m@th#1\cdot$}\fi\fi\fi
    }%
    \advance\dimen@ by -\ht0 %
    \dimen@=.5\dimen@
    \hidewidth\raise\dimen@\box0\hidewidth
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \bigcupdot a=\biguplus mn\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parametrize the scaling factor:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\bigcupdot}{%
  \mathop{%
    \vphantom{\bigcup}%
    \mathpalette\@bigcupdot{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@bigcupdot}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\bigcup$\cr
    \sbox0{$#1\bigcup$}%
    \dimen@=\ht0 %
    \advance\dimen@ by -\dp0
    \sbox0{\scalebox{\@dotscale{#1}}{$\m@th#1\cdot$}}%
    \advance\dimen@ by -\ht0
    \dimen@=.5\dimen@
    \hidewidth\raise\dimen@\box0\hidewidth
  }%
}
\newcommand{\@dotscale}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle 1.7\else\ifx#1\textstyle 1.4\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle 1.2\else 1.1\fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\bigcupdot$
$\textstyle\bigcupdot$
$\scriptstyle\bigcupdot$
$\scriptscriptstyle\bigcupdot$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much!