# Problem with MathOperators

Tags: math-operators

When I write this `MathOperator` (that I invented), the output of this code is not well. How could improve it? Thank you so much

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stix}

\DeclareMathOperator{\bigdotcup}{\bigcup\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\;\;\cdot}

\begin{document}

\Large

\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation}
\bigdotcup_{i=1}^n
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Basically just [amsmath - Mathematical symbol for disjoint set union - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3964/mathematical-symbol-for-disjoint-set-union). Maybe see also [math operators - How to make dot in the defined bigcupdot automatically change size? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611630/how-to-make-dot-in-the-defined-bigcupdot-automatically-change-size) if needed.

Comment: @user202729 but those answers are for faking the character with ams fonts so don't so much apply here with stix fonts that have ⨃ in the font

Comment: What's the purpose of `\Large` which you always add to your examples?

Comment: I've never noticed it, it's my habit

Comment: Well, don't. Anyway, if you do `texdoc stix`, you find the symbol on page 19, section 4.7 Big operators.

Comment: @Puck i hope you only do it in examples here, not in real documents, having body text larger than section headings would be weird

Comment: Why?? I always use `\Large` in real documents (my articles, my books, ...).

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand

Comment: @Puck if you use `\Large` in that way the body text will be larger than the text of (sub)section headings, which will look very strange also you have large text but the vertical spaces around list items, math display, ... are the values designed for normal size , not increased. The whole document will look very unbalanced.

Comment: Ok thank you for answer. How could I make sections larger, using `\Large` for the text? Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want `\bigcupdot` ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stix}% or better: \usepackage{stix2}


\begin{document}

\Large

\section{Introduction}


\begin{equation}
\bigcupdot_{i=1}^n
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```