# Place symbol inside of \bigsqcup

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

How can I place a symbol inside of `\bigsqcup`?

What I have tried is this:

```
\newcommand{\concn}{\bigsqcup_{i=1}^n\hspace{-1.07em}\text{\footnotesize $h$\normalsize\hspace{0.6em}}}
```

The problem ist that this only looks nice in an equation enviroment. When I use it inside of text, then my `hspaces` are no longer correct:

[image]

Is there a method to place the `h` inside of `\bigsqcup` which works in any environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variation on [Mathematical symbol for disjoint set union](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3964/mathematical-symbol-for-disjoint-set-union)

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter % \moverlay by D. Arsenau
\def\moverlay{\mathpalette\mov@rlay}
\def\mov@rlay#1#2{\leavevmode\vtop{%
   \baselineskip\z@skip \lineskiplimit-\maxdimen
   \ialign{\hfil$\m@th#1##$\hfil\cr#2\crcr}}}

\newcommand{\charfusion}[3][\mathord]{
    #1{\ifx#1\mathop\vphantom{#2}\fi
        \mathpalette\mov@rlay{#2\cr#3}
      }
    \ifx#1\mathop\expandafter\displaylimits\fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\bighsqcup}{\charfusion[\mathop]{\bigsqcup}{\innerh}}
\newcommand{\innerh}{\mathchoice
  {h}
  {\scriptstyle h}
  {\scriptscriptstyle h}
  {\scriptscriptstyle h}
}

\begin{document}
$\bighsqcup_{i=1}^n$
\[
\bighsqcup_{i=1}^n
\bigsqcup_{i=1}^n % for comparison
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 (of course) I used `ooalign` in my answer, using some of your previous work... Is there a reason you didn't go with it?

Comment: @cmhughes The `\m@verlay` macro is actually very similar to `\ooalign` (just a different setting of `\lineskip`). This macro by D. Arsenau can be found in the comprehensive list of symbols; so I use it without trying to change it into `\ooalign`.

Comment: @egreg OMG, I never would have tought it would be as difficult as that! ;-) Thanks!

Comment: @lpdbw Difficult? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg How can I achieve that the symbol inside `\bigsqcup` is smaller? Background is that I also want a similar symbol with `\mathfrak{u}_0` inside, but then ((with the current definitions) this is too big to fit inside `\bigsqcup`.

Comment: @lpdbw Add `\scriptstyle` in the first argument to `\mathchoice` (where the single `h` is now) and change the `\scriptstyle` in the other three arguments to `\scriptscriptstyle`; you won't be using the symbol in second level sub/superscripts, I hope.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option using `ooalign`; I wonder if there's a reason that egreg didn't use it- if he tells me to delete this answer, I will :)

[image: screenshot]

The de facto reference on this site for `ooalign` is egreg's answer to [\subseteq + \circ as a single symbol ("open subset")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset) but you'll see it used in various answers.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\bighsqcup}{%
    \mathchoice%
    {% displaystyle
        \ooalign{$\displaystyle\bigsqcup_{i=1}^n$\cr
            \hidewidth{\footnotesize $h\mkern2mu$}
    }}
    {% textstyle
        \ooalign{$\textstyle\bigsqcup_{i=1}^n$\cr%
            \hidewidth{\footnotesize $h\mkern25mu$}
    }}
    {% scriptstyle
        \ooalign{$\scriptstyle\bigsqcup_{i=1}^n$\cr%
            \hidewidth{\tiny $h\mkern24mu$}
    }}
    {% scriptscriptstyle
        \ooalign{$\scriptstyle\bigsqcup_{i=1}^n$\cr%
            \hidewidth{\tiny $h\mkern24mu$}
    }}
}

\begin{document}

$\bighsqcup_{\bighsqcup}$

\[
    \bighsqcup
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can tweak the `\hspace` values in the `\mathchoice`s to better match the centering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\stacktype{L}
\newlength\cupsize
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\bigsqcup}
\newcommand\filledcup[3]{%
\mathchoice%
{%
    \stackengine{0pt}{$\displaystyle\foo_{#2}^{#3}$}%
      {$\displaystyle #1$}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}%
}{%
    \setlength\cupsize{\widthof{$\textstyle\bigsqcup$}}
    \stackengine{0pt}{$\textstyle\foo_{#2}^{#3}$}%
      {$\textstyle\hspace{.13\cupsize}#1$}{O}{l}{F}{T}{L}%
}{%
    \setlength\cupsize{\widthof{$\scriptstyle\bigsqcup$}}
    \stackengine{0pt}{$\scriptstyle\foo_{#2}^{#3}$}%
      {$\scriptstyle\hspace{.13\cupsize}#1$}{O}{l}{F}{T}{L}%
}{%
    \setlength\cupsize{\widthof{$\scriptscriptstyle\bigsqcup$}}
    \stackengine{0pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle\foo_{#2}^{#3}$}%
      {$\scriptscriptstyle\hspace{.08\cupsize}#1$}{O}{l}{F}{T}{L}%
}%
}
\begin{document}
\centering
This is inline: \( \filledcup{h}{i=1}{n} U_i \)
\[ \filledcup{h}{i=9991}{n} U_i \]
\[ A_{\filledcup{h}{i=1}{n} U_i} \]
\[ \scriptscriptstyle \filledcup{h}{i=1}{n} U_i \]
\end{document}
```

[image]