# Enter the symbol in math mode

Tags: symbols

Can anybody tell me how to enter `$\bigcupdot\limits$`? Thanks.
I know how to enter `\bigcupdot`, but I don't know how to follow it by `\limits`.

Comment: \makeatother
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\bigcupdot}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@bigcupdot{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@bigcupdot}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\bigcup$\cr
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1\cdot$\hidewidth
  }%
}
\makeatother

Comment: Don't add code in comments (it doesn't format in a readable way) you can _edit_ your question and add the code in a code block using the `{}` button. (and add some text saying what the code is doing)

Comment: You find a way to define `\bigcupdot` here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52673/4427 It won't require any `\limits`