# Bug in unicode-math or lualatex?

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand{\dotcup}{\ensuremath{\mathaccent\cdot\cup}}

\begin{document}
$a \dotcup b$
\end{document}
```

If compiled with `lualatex` I get the following error

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./min.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 2
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
...
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\cdot 
l.8 $a \dotcup
             b$
...
```

On the other hand if I compile the example without `unicode-math` but with `pdflatex`, then I get the desired PDF file. Is this a bug in `unicode-math` or `lualatex`?

**Edit:**
The command `\dotcup` is given as an example in the file `symbols-a4.pdf` where it serves as an example in order to center two symbols over each other. In the end, I am not interested in that particular symbol but in a composition of two other symbols where I receive the same error. That means, it served me as a general example in order to determine if this is a bug or intended behavior.

Comment: Why are you using \cdot? Why not `\dot\cup`?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, I took the example from the symbols-a4.pdf where it served as an example in order to center symbols over each other (p. 210)

Comment: @MaxMaier If you want to compose two other symbols, why asking for different ones?

Comment: @egreg Well I thought it would be a good idea to take a probably known example from a "standard" paper (symbols-a4.pdf). Actually, I didn't ask for these symbols, did I? Again, I was wondering about the error message if this has something to do with unicode-math or lualatex, i.e., if this is a bug or not. But I see your point. Next time I will phrase my question differently. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of `\mathaccent` and `\cdot` are very different in legacy LaTeX and `unicode-math`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newcommand{\cdotaccent}{\Umathaccent fixed "7 "2 `⋅ }

\newcommand{\dotcup}{\mathbin{\cdotaccent\cup}}

\begin{document}
$a \dotcup b$
\end{document}
```

Of course `\ensuremath` is useless, whereas `\mathbin` gives the expected spacing.

[image]

Comment: actually \mathaccent still seems to be the primitive (at least \show says \mathaccent=\mathaccent) but it seems to want a \Umathaccent spec anyway in the OPs context)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The problem is that `\cdot` is not defined via `\Umathchardef`, so it's not legal in the context of a number.

Comment: to my eyes, the dot looks too high.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Possibly, but the one in `\cupdot` is too low. Anyway, the OP says it's not really the required symbol.

Comment: @egreg -- being eternally picky, i checked the monotype symbols list.  the dot is definitely centered vertically -- as would be expected if both the cup and the dot are aligned on the math axis.  (yes, i know that this was just a standin for a general formula, and that there's a formula for `\dotcup` in the comprehensive symbols list, but i believe the alignment-on-math-axis principle holds except in very special/exceptional cases, of which this isn't one.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'd do the superposition in a different way, of course, which wouldn't raise the dot. I just followed the OP's preference. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52673/4427

Comment: I wasn't aware of the fact that mathaccent behaves differently in unicode-math. Thanks for pointing this out! I will dive into it.

Answer (score 3):

The usage is very odd (`\mathaccent` takes a number not a character as the specifier) although it sort of works if you give it a `\mathchardef` token as it re-interprets the mathcode as a mathaccent.

`unicode-math` changes the definition of `\cdot` (and most symbols) to be `\let` to the unicode character rather than a `\mathchardef` defined token, so it is not a valid number.

However  even for pdftex the definition seems unfortunate as you probably want a `\mathbin` operator to use like `\cup`

I think you want U+228D (⊍) so

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}



\begin{document}


$a \cupdot b$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that there is a luatex bug. \cdot is (after \begin{document}!) no a \mathchar but a simple character: `\cdot=the character ⋅`

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, thanks for your help! I took the example from the standard paper `symbols-a4.pdf`. I'm actually looking for other symbols, it just served as an example for the problem with lualatex/unicode-math and mathaccent. That means, I was wondering if this is a bug in general or not.