# Sign for equivalence relation “on the same hyperbola”

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I want a symbol for an equivalence relation meaning “on the same hyperbola $xy=c$”.

Is there a standard notation? If not, I'm thinking of something on the tune of

[image: hyperbolic equivalence]

Any idea of a similar sign, or how to build one, by stacking or otherwise, in a way compatible with arXiv, LNCS and AMS environments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your symbol is a bit complicated. Since I know of no standard symbol, I suggest this:

[image]

which is formed by overlaying two standard symbols (`\asymp` and `-`) and requires no additional packages. It looks (to me) like a hyperbolic version of `\equiv` (`≡`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\samehyp}{\mathrel{\ooalign{\hfil$\asymp$\hfil\cr\hfil$-$\hfil\cr}}}

\begin{document}

$(a,b)\samehyp(c,d)$

\end{document}
```

For general instructions on how to build your own symbols, I suggest [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768/125871) and its answers.

Note: If you plan to use this symbol in `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle` you will need a more complicated version that will adapt to style changes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\newcommand{\samehyp}{\mathrel{\ooalign{\hfil$\asymp$\hfil\cr\hfil$-$\hfil\cr}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\samehyp}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\s@mehyp\relax}}
\newcommand{\s@mehyp}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\asymp$\cr
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1-$\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$(a,b)\samehyp(c,d)_{(a,b)\samehyp(c,d)_{(a,b)\samehyp(c,d)}}$

\end{document}
```

If you really want the symbol you sketched, you'll probably have to design it yourself. I suggest `tikz` (for designing the symbol) and `scalerel` to make it the same size as a symbol of your choice (I picked `+`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,scalerel}

\newcommand{\samehyp}{\mathrel{\scalerel*{\tikz{\draw[line width=2pt](0,.3)--(1,.3)(0,.5)--(1,.5)(0,.7)--(1,.7)(.6,1)to[out=-90,in=180](1,.6)(.4,0)to[out=90,in=0](0,.4);}}{+}}}

\begin{document}

$(a,b)\samehyp(c,d)$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks. The combination of `\asymp` and `-` has the advantage of simplicity and readability. The code given works nicely when standalone, but for some reason fails in my ams context. A workaround for me was to use the `\makeatletter…\makeatother` found [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52673/46187) then `\newcommand{\samehyp}{\charfusion[\mathbin]{\asymp}{-}}`